# UIView Category causing unrecognized selector error

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewanimation, objective-c-category

I have a UIView Category that is causing an error that I cannot figure out this is the .h for the category:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BCRectEdge) {
    BCRectEdgeTop    = 0,
    BCRectEdgeLeft   = 1,
    BCRectEdgeBottom = 2,
    BCRectEdgeRight  = 3
};

@interface UIView (Genie)

/*
 * After the animation has completed the view's transform will be changed to match the destination's rect, i.e.
 * view's transform (and thus the frame) will change, however the bounds and center will *not* change.
 */

- (void)genieInTransitionWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                      destinationRect:(CGRect)destRect
                      destinationEdge:(BCRectEdge)destEdge
                           completion:(void (^)())completion;



/*
 * After the animation has completed the view's transform will be changed to CGAffineTransformIdentity.
 */

- (void)genieOutTransitionWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                             startRect:(CGRect)startRect
                             startEdge:(BCRectEdge)startEdge
                            completion:(void (^)())completion;

@end
```

And then it I import it into a view controller.  Create a new UIView and use one of those methods.  It suggests this method as I start typing, and if I define it, it goes to the right place.  But when I run it, it says:

```
'-[UIView genieInTransitionWithDuration:destinationRect:destinationEdge:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1552c220'
```

Any thoughts?  Driving me crazy.

Comment: Do you import UIView+Genie.h file into your viewcontroller ?

Comment: Ya I figured it out, when I added the files to my project it didn't add to the target

Answer (score 0):

The extension didn't get added to the target when it was created for some reason.  Adding it fixed the issue.

Comment: Please, mark your answer as solution so that this question goes aways from unanswered.

Comment: I can't for 2 days it says